# Need to get time part

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

I have got string like this

```
string p = "v 0 fl 0x4; value 8 feat 0; sn 0809099; mn -; tim 2015-10-11 20:50:36 8 Access Points"
```

How can i get the only this part from above string "**2015-10-11 20:50:36**". 
Could any one please help on this parsing the string and only time retrieval form string.

Many thanks in advance..

Comment: Search for "tim " and use the next 19 characters?

Comment: "2015-10-11 20:50:36" is date and time, not time.

Comment: `Regex r = new Regex(@"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}");`

Comment: sorry guys I am bad at regex ...

Comment: why these many downvotes .. I stated that I am bad at regex...

Comment: @EnigmaState Please undelete your last question, I have a solution for you.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i did undo that ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must say thanks to `user853710` for a quick pattern. This will help you to collect the date from the given sting, and [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) plays the key role in the extraction process:

```
string pattern = @"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}";
string p = "v 0 fl 0x4; value 8 feat 0; sn AC0809099; mn -; tim 2015-10-11 20:50:36 8 Access Points";
string[] pArray = p.Split(';');
DateTime dtOutput;
if (pArray[4] != null) {
    string match = Regex.Match(pArray[4], pattern).Value;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(match, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out dtOutput);
}

// dtOutput will hold the required date
```

Answer (score 2):

Match it with regex, here is the string

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}
```